# Translate Delphi asm to C++ Builder asm

Tags: delphi, assembly, c++builder

I am trying to convert part of a Delphi project to a C++Builder project.

I reduced the problem to the following code:

```pascal
procedure Test;
asm
    MOV     EAX, OFFSET @test
@test:
    db 00H
end;
```

If I try to compile this, and several variations, I get an error:

> [BCC32 Fehler] Unit1.cpp(21): E2451 Undefiniertes Symbol '@test'

Can anybody help?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what you have tried that did not work for you.

Comment: That's nonsense; `00` is the opcode for a memory-destination [add](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/add), but it takes a ModRM byte.  So the full instruction following the `mov eax, imm32` will depend on whatever's in memory after the `00` byte.  If it's another `0` of padding, it'll be `add [eax], al`.  Either way, execution will then fall into whatever's next.  Unless Delphi implicitly puts `@label` labels in a different section and implicitly adds a `ret` instruction or expects execution to fall through an inline(?) asm block?

Comment: @PeterCordes "*Unless Delphi implicitly puts `@label` labels in a different section*" - [it does not](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Assembler_Syntax). "*and implicitly adds a `ret` instruction*" - [it does](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Assembly_Procedures_and_Functions), in this case.

Comment: But does it add the `C3 ret` *before* the `db 0`?  If not, the machine code becomes `00 C3  add bl,al`.  From the doc you linked, that's what I'd expect.  With no params or locals, it would be the`ret` that gets skipped / consumed, rather than part of a `mov esp,ebp` or `pop ebp`, although either of those would also be fatal.

Comment: I think you are both missing the point ... I expect this is just a minimal part of the asm code that produce the error ... and the full code is not returning eax nor jumping at the `db` location but using that for whatever ... and the problem is how to add `label` to `asm` so that C++ compiler does not complain

Comment: @Spektre: Yes, I highly suspect their real code isn't like this, that's why I'm complaining that the [mcve] they posted doesn't represent what they probably actually want to do.  At least a `ret` before the `db 0` would make a *huge* difference to this, although it's still weird to want the address of constant data directly following the machine code.  But yeah maybe they just wanted to repro the error message, not show code that makes any sense.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has some problems like You **can not forward reference labels** in C++ `asm` with one exception (`jmp` instruction)...

The inbuild help and online one too:

- [Embarcadero Assembler Syntax](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Assembler_Syntax)

suggest that the syntax for labels is the same as in Pascal ... that is true **however usage of labels is very different !!! up to a point they are almost useless** I still did not get it to work even after 15+ years they changed it as you can use labels only for jumps and maybe calls but nothing else...

Perhaps there is some directive or keyword that allows label usage but have not found any yet as all examples are in pascal syntax which does not work in C++ environment.

Another problem is that you use `test` label ... **You are forgetting that `test` is assembly instruction so the names are in conflict!!!**

You can still workaround:

1. **reorder your code so you do not need forward referencing**

   This is doable as `jmp` is still working as should with labels however you can forget about simple selfmodifying code...
2. **convert your local asm variables to C++ local variables**

   local C++ variables are directly accessible from `asm`. Beware function operands are not so if you need them copy them into local variables first.
3. **convert addressing syntax to C++**

   You know this:

   ```
   MOV     EAX, OFFSET @test
   ```

   Is not doing what you intend in C++ you have to use `LEA` instruction instead of `OFFSET` ... just create a breakpoint and see what the `OFFSET` will return (in my case its always `0xFFFFFFFF` instead of real address) while `LEA` obtains correct address.

**Putting all together You can try something like this instead:**

```
void asmtest()
    {
    BYTE a=0x00;
    asm {
        lea eax,a
        }
    }
```

In case you have a really nasty code you can also convert the code into fully assembler code (no C++) and compile as asm code instead ... Then compiled/linked obj file can be linked into your C++ project. IIRC in BCB5 was an option for this however haven't use that for many years so this feature might be removed however you can still compile with any assembler (TASM,NASM...) borland was always compatible with TASM (as it was used internaly) so I recommend to use that to avoid additional problems...

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to translate assembler to assembler at all? The code you showed is defining a single byte in memory and then returning its memory address to the caller. That can and should be written in native C++ instead, let the compiler handle creating the necessary assembler for you, ie:

```cpp
const char* Test() {
    static const char ch = 0;
    return &ch;
}
```

Comment: This has `static const char ch=0` as data, not as part of the machine code (the opcode for a memory-destination `add`, with operands specified by whatever byte comes next in memory!)  This also returns, unlike the code in the question which falls through to whatever is next, tail-calling the next function in the code section (if the add doesn't fault).  This is a reasonable guess at what the OP actually wanted to do, if the asm they posted wasn't what they actual have, or if Delphi implicitly adds a `ret` instruction before and `@label`.  And yeah, definitely better to avoid inline asm.

Comment: @PeterCordes In the assembler shown, `db 00H` defines a single "data byte" with a value of 0x00 in memory, and identifies it as `@test`. The function is simply storing the address of that byte into `EAX`, effectively returning it to the caller. Hence the use of a `static` variable in my C++ example.

Comment: Yeah, I know what `db 00h` does.  But look where it's placed: right after a `mov`, so execution reaches it!  It doesn't only (or at all) *return* it, it also executes it.  If that was a bug (or Delphi magically inserts a `ret` or puts `@test: db 0` in another section), then yes this C is equivalent.

Comment: @PeterCordes "*It doesn't only return it, it also executes it*" - hm, good point. That is odd. "*or Delphi magically inserts a `ret`*" - [it does](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Assembly_Procedures_and_Functions), in this case. "*or puts `@test: db 0` in another section*" - [it does not](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Assembler_Syntax).